# C# WebForm - Set focus of textbox with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms

I have a Javascript that when i write in one textbox, it fills another textbox. But i need that   the focus stay in a third textbox.

Actually, my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function SelectValue(source, eventArgs) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtCodeProduct.ClientID %>').value = eventArgs.get_value();
            document.getElementById('<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>').focus();
            }
</script>
```

but the focus don't work...If i put an alert in a code, the focus work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function SelectValue(source, eventArgs) {
            document.getElementById('<%= txtCodeProduct.ClientID %>').value = eventArgs.get_value();
            document.getElementById('<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>').focus();
            alert("test");
            }
```

How i resolve this without use alert ?
My textbox are in a form that uses update panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 function SelectValue(source, eventArgs) {
    document.getElementById('<%= txtCodeProduct.ClientID %>').value = eventArgs.get_value();
    setTimeout( function(){
            document.getElementById('<%= txtQuantity.ClientID %>').focus();
        }, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Asp.Net do you use? otherwise you can use `ClientIDMode`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCodeProduct" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity"    runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

I also recommend using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SelectValue(source, eventArgs) {
        $("#txtCodeProduct").val(eventArgs.get_value());
        $("#txtQuantity").focus();
    }
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus/